Undefined Bus error in Docker Logs while setting up SQL Server using docker-compose.yaml
While setting up Docker container for a SQL Server using a docker-compose.yaml file, after running the script it's showing this error in Logs as the container keeps exiting & restarting
DOCKER LOG DATA:
nt.sh': Operation not permitted
2024-08-15 08:24:35 mssql_container  | Bus error
2024-08-15 08:24:49 mssql_container  | SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
2024-08-15 08:24:49 mssql_container  | This container is running as user mssql.
2024-08-15 08:24:49 mssql_container  | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
2024-08-15 08:24:49 mssql_container  | chmod: changing permissions of './entrypoi

At first I had tried manually entering the script commands via CMD, but then I decided to execute the whole script list using a docker.compose.yaml file thinking hopefully it'll run smoothly

I created a simple application and connected to SQL Server via docker-compose.yaml file.

The error message you're encountering mainly occurs due to insufficient resources in host system or docker container environment.
Make sure your computer has enough resources to run SQL Server in a Docker container.

This is my docker-compose.yaml file:
version: '3.8'
services:
app_service:
build: .
container_name: app_service
environment:
 - CONNECTION_STRING=Server=tcp:<your_server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<your_database_name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<your_username>;Password=<your_password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
ports:
 - "8080:80"
volumes:
 - .:/usr/src/app


Ensure that the correct database username and password are included in your connection string.
In your SQL Server settings, go to the Networking tab and add your IP address to the firewall rules.


After making the above changes, my SQL Server connected successfully.
Docker logs:

